# Using "nen" instead of "einen"

Tags: usage, abbreviation

Would one sound like a native German speaker saying "nen" instead of "einen" or is there another special point behind it? Does it have colloquial usage only?

Comment: If you really want to sound like a native, you shouldn't restrict your usage of *nen* to *einen* but also *einer* and *eine*. In my experience especially in chats but sometimes in sloppy speech it is used like that. Personally I despise this usage and it absolutely drives me nuts.

Comment: If you want to replace "einen" with an emphasis on the number one (Example: "Ich kenne nur *einen* Menschen der Linkshänder ist.") then "nen" doesn't work.

Comment: Make it even shorter: Use *n* instead: "Ich kenn da 'n Typ, der besorgt dir alles!" Female form: *'ne*: "Haste mal 'ne Mark?" (Hast Du eine D-Mark, und bist Du willens, sie mir zu schenken?)

Comment: Be sure to use an apostrophe when writing "nen" instead of "einen", since you're omitting letters there.

Comment: @musiKk I don't think anybody does that in *spoken* language. I've never heard "Haste mal nen Mark?".

Comment: @fzwo: That's a bad example because it is an expression in itself. I heard the wrong *nen* more often than I want to remember...

Comment: @musiKk: Sagen Leute echt "Das ist ja nen geile Maschine"? Allerdings - es stimmt, bei sächlichem Geschlecht hört man es tatsächlich leider manchmal: "Das ist ja nen geiles Teil".

Comment: Dear Gigli, my advice: if you are not a native speaker *never* use slang or "cute" expressions or abbreviations. Nothing is more ridiculous than foreigners with dreadful syntax, grotesque pronunciation   and ultra-limited lexicon trying to sound cool (I'm not implying  you do, of course: *you* is the generic pronoun here!). If you want to impress people, use  standard grammar, pronounce  words correctly and enrich your active vocabulary.

Comment: Nice point @GeorgesElencwajg. I'll try to follow your advice, thank you.

Comment: Dear Gigli, once more this is not meant for you. It's just some recurring rant I'm delivering at the slightest pretext!

Answer (score 8):

Yes to both questions. It's only used in colloquial speech by native speakers or when chatting online with friends.

Comment: SMS (12 more to go - never use it in comments :), they need to have _at least_ 16 chars).

Answer (score 6):

The use of "nen" instead of "einen" is colloquial speech. It doesn't deliver any additional meaning, much like the abbreviation of "does not" to "doesn't". You should never use it in formal German, but especially in spoken language it is often used.

Attention:
As pointed out in the comments to your question, "einen" is shortened to "'nen", but "eine" is shortened to "'ne" and "ein" to "'n" - you simply replace the "ei-" by an apostrophe.